# How should I troubleshoot my Google Contributor Licence Agreement Issue on my pull request?

Tags: git, git-commit, pull-request, pull, googlebot

I have made the Pull Request to [this project](https://github.com/google/mentornet), which is owned by google. So, google asks for Contributor Licence Agreement. which I have signed [here](https://cla.developers.google.com/clas). I have created CLA.

Firsly, I thought that there are two email addresses in my github account. So, I have also created CLA for both email IDs.

For committing the code, I am using simple approach : 
        git add .
        git commit -m 'Message'
        git push -u origin branch_name

[Pull Request](https://github.com/google/mentornet/pull/7)

Still the google-bot is not able to verify my CLA. It is giving me error like below :

Error Message :
We found a Contributor License Agreement for you (the sender of this pull request), but were unable to find agreements for all the commit author(s) or Co-authors. If you authored these, maybe you used a different email address in the git commits than was used to sign the CLA (login here to double check)? If these were authored by someone else, then they will need to sign a CLA as well, and confirm that they're okay with these being contributed to Google.
In order to pass this check, please resolve this problem and have the pull request author add another comment and the bot will run again. If the bot doesn't comment, it means it doesn't think anything has changed.

I have created CLA for both the email IDs which are associated with my Github Account.

I have enabled Two Factor Authentication.

I have committed again and again to check. 
I have commented on PR to check whether problem is resolved by google-bot or not.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Message'
git push -u origin branch_name
```

Please describe the complete solution if someone has faced this issue in past and resolved it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commits have been made with 3 different email addresses, one each:

- @iiitk.ac.in
- @gmail.com
- @delhivery.com

You can see this from your branch by doing a `git log -n3`

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, this is related to having a diferent set of user info on the commit and de CLA. Use `git log` to view the commit logs for your repository (hit q to exit).

You can also view your user settings:

*Actual Repo config*

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

*Global config*

```
git config --global user.email
git config --global user.email
```

**Some sugestions on how to fix this error**

- Fix your configuration issues, create a new branch and do a new pull request. You can edit the author for a single commit using:

```
git commit --author="max kellerman<max@kellerman.org>"
```

1. If possible, add all the emails in question to a google group CLA so they can be authorized contributors.
2. You can try to edit the Author information for previous commits:

*Change author details for the very last commit:*

```
git commit --amend --author="max kellerman<max@kellerman.org>"
```

To change multiple commits on the same branch, you can use [interactive rebase or branch filtering](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email/#using-interactive-rebase)